# SQL - conditions during query

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically i want through all the 0's on my database and then start going through the 2's.

The query is:

```
   SELECT IP,Time,HostName
     FROM RoughScan
CASE WHEN EXISTS (DeepScan=0) 
     THEN (DeepScan=0 LIMIT 1) 
     ELSE (DeepScan=2 LIMIT 1)
```

but i get the error saying:

> Unexpected end of CASE expression (near "" at position 0)

Also i am using MariaDB Server.

Comment: WHERE not CASE. etc

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you want to do is quite unclear.

Comment: "Basically i want through all the 0's on my database and then start going through the 2's." Do you mean you want to sort the results, or filter the results?

Comment: Hi, I only want one row to be returned. which will be a row which contains `DeepScan`=0. If their is not any data that has `DeepScan`=0 then i want to return any `DeepScan`=2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply CASE to WHERE like this:

```
SELECT IP,Time,HostName
FROM RoughScan
WHERE 
  DeepScan = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RoughScan WHERE DeepScan = 0) THEN 0 
    ELSE 2 
  END
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row of each type, then use `union all`:

```
(SELECT `IP`,`Time`,`HostName`
 FROM `RoughScan`
 WHERE DeepScan = 0
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `IP`,`Time`,`HostName`
 FROM `RoughScan`
 WHERE DeepScan = 2
 LIMIT 1
);
```

Note that `ORDER BY` is usually used with `LIMIT`.